# Ant: Add files to zip only if path is defined

Tags: ant

I have to create an ant target that will add component .jar to a zip. The problem is that I do not have the version of component always defined. For example:

```
    <zip destfile="${dist.dir}\result-${result-version}.zip">
       <fileset dir="${dist.dir}" includes="maincomponent-${maincomponenet-version}*.jar"/>
       <fileset dir="${second-componenet-folder}" includes="${second-component-version}.jar" />
   </zip>
```

How can I add some condition that will create the zip with the main component if the `second-component-version` property is not defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Condition](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) and `isset` ([conditions](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html)):

```
<target name="zip">
    <fileset id="main" dir="${dist.dir}" includes="maincomponent-${maincomponenet-version}.jar" />
    <fileset id="component" dir="${second-componenet-folder}" includes="${second-component-version}.jar" />
    <condition property="jar.file" value="component" else="main">
        <isset property="second-component-version"/>
    </condition>
    <zip destfile="${dist.dir}/result-${result-version}.zip">
        <fileset refid="${jar.file}" />
    </zip>
</target>
```

Comment: will this add both files if the second-component-version is supplied?

Comment: is it easy changeable to include both if second component is defined and only the main if the second variable is not set? I have many components to add in this way

Comment: You can either create a third combined `fileset` element from the parent directory to include both files, or use [`union`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#union) to combined the two original `fileset`s